# Split ActivatedRoute queryParams subscription into multiple subscriptions

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular7

I want to get Angular ActivatedRoute queryParams changes and execute a function just once and other function every time.

So far the way I found is subscribing twice but I want a better way to do it, maybe using some `pipe` operator.

```
// DO SOMETHING THE FIRST TIME
this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
      .pipe(
        first(),
        switchMap(params => {
          // HTTP CALL
        })
      )
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        // DO SOMETHING
      }); 

// DO SOMETHING ALWAYS
this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
      .subscribe((params: any) => {
        // DO SOMETHING
      });
```

Is there any other way do this, something like `splitSubscription` operator??

Answer (score 1):

One approach can be something like this,

```
visited = false;
this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.pipe(
  tap(_ => {
    //do your always thing
  }),
  filter(_ => !this.visited),
  tap(_ => {
    this.visited = true;
    // do your one time thing
  })
).subscribe();
```

Instead of tap, you can have your own set of operators, the thing to notice is, filtering this way will allow only once to go down and there you can have your one-time implementation.

Comment: I have it implemented like this. Using a flag but I have to subscribe twice like before. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you will need to subscribe it twice. If you can show what you implemented may be we can improve your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor a bit, rather than trying to subscribe multiple times to the `activatedRoute.queryParamMap` - not sure if the split operator you're asking about is possible. The following pattern is pretty standard

```typescript
// Class properties
private paramMapSubject = new BehaviourSubject<ParamMap>(null);
// Using a public observable if your binding to components, or exposing in a service
public params$ = this.paramMapSubject.asObservable();

// In your constructor
// componentDestroyed$ is a subject that's nexted in ngOnDestroy
this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(componentDestroyed$)
        tap( params => {
          this.paramMapSubject.next(params)
        }),
      )
      .subscribe();

// In ngOnInit - will only be called once - if it's in a component
this.params$.pipe(
  takeOne(),
  tap( params => {
    // Do Something Once
  }).subscribe()

this.params$.pipe(
  takeUntil(componentDestroyed$)
  tap( params => {
    // Do Something continuously
  }).subscribe()
```

Comment: I saw this solution with a `Subject` but I have to subscribe twice either way. Thanks.